# Create a QR Code and show it in ImageView

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am creating an app which will be able to scan QR code and create QR code. The scanning part is done and its working fine. But when I try to create the QR code and show it in an ImageView the QR code created is not containing correct text. I am using ZXING library.

```
Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<>();
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

QRCodeWriter qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeEncoder.encode(myText, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        200, 200, hintMap);

height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
width = bitMatrix.getWidth();

final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

for (x = 0; x < width; x++){
    bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
}

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr_code);
myImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Is the imageview visible in layout file?

Comment: Yes. The visibility is set to VISIBLE

Comment: I hope you have initialized the height, width etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the for loop. You missed a inner for loop. But how come you were getting a blank image!

Use below snippet.

```
for (x = 0; x < width; x++){
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++){
        bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try out full code:

```
    com.google.zxing.Writer writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    // String finaldata = Uri.encode(data, "utf-8");
    int width = 250;
    int height = 250;
    BitMatrix bm = writer
            .encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
    Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {// width
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {// height
            ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK
                    : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
```

Works !!